# Sending data from one phone to another

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization

Hi I am trying to send a simple message from one windows 8 phone to another. The Text string "hello" for example. I have been doing some research but I cant seem to find a example of this online or a tutorial on the subject. I know I have to serialize the data which has something to do with binary but im not sure what. Must I send it through a server or can I send it phone to phone directly. The best tutorial I have found is this one but it still uses the phones sms I want to do it from app to app. [The Tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Employees_app_with_XML_parsing_and_messaging_in_WP)

Comment: You should be more specific, how do you want to send it, how it should be received, in your app or directly by phone without your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You are looking For Sending Data(text/Image/some other) from one device to another. So you need to go for WP8/7 Networking like Http,Sockets and proximitiy. 
Hope this Below Link's Help You 
Video Link => [Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-222)

Find the Code Sample => [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/HTTP-and-Socket-API-e38ac69e)

Hope this Helps You